# How to set Cols and Lines for a Subprocess

Tags: shell-script, scripting, gnu-screen, tmux, subshell

I have a script that runs a series of scripts numbered 001,002,003,004... etc down to 041 right now, will be more in the future - and these scripts them selves use some cursor control to print a progress bar and other status information and get the width and height of the terminal from `tput cols` and `tput lines` respectively.

Without rewriting the sub-scripts, I would like to reserve *one* line at the bottom for *overall* status information for the outer script. I was curious if there was a way to set what tput replies for lines and cols.

There must be a way because tmux achieves it. I was thinking there may be an environmental variable but the only change I can see that tmux makes when running env is setting the $TERM to screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: WRT tmux, the stuff in that is running *inside* tmux, which provides multiple shells and windows.  Ie, it is not doing this via shell commands. So going that route means writing a pretty serious application.

Comment: Well it has to be altering something tput is reading, I tried looking up the source of tput but didn't understand it at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will let you customize the number of lines and cols tput returns

```
export LINES=1000
export COLUMNS=1000
```

Answer (score 3):

Reading the source would be definitive, but for the fainthearted, the manual is the place to go.  If there is no command-line option, the terminal database in combination with environment variables will provide your script with whatever it might need:

- The [`tput`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html) manual page does not mention environment variables.
- But in the [See Also](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html#h2-SEE-ALSO) section, it refers you to [curs_termcap(3x)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_termcap.3x.html), the manual for the termcap  interface (functions).
- On that page, [Formatting Capabilities](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_termcap.3x.html#h3-FORMATTING-CAPABILITIES) is relevant, pointing to `tputs` on the [`curs_terminfo(3x)`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html) page.
- Again (see [Output Functions](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html#h3-Output-Functions)) no explicit mention of environment variables.

Searching for enlightenment, you might try the [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html) manual page.

- In the section on [Environment](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h2-ENVIRONMENT), it lists `LINES` and `COLUMNS`.
- In [`LINES`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-LINES), it just says to see `COLUMNS`.
- [`COLUMNS`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-COLUMNS) gives more information:

> Specify the width of the screen in  characters.   Applications  running in a windowing environment usually are able
>   to obtain the width of the window in which they  are  executing.   If  neither the `COLUMNS` value nor the terminal's
>   screen size is available, *ncurses* uses the size which  may
>   be  specified  in  the  terminfo  database (i.e., the `cols`
>   capability).

Now, for this question, it would have been nice if the manual page were more direct, saying that `tput` uses `tputs` for output and also uses `setupterm` for initialization.  Occasionally (when this information is readily available in the changelog) no one notices that it is not explicit in the manual.  For instance this item from [2002](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20021012):

```
    + modify setupterm() to ensure that it initializes the baudrate, for
      applications such as tput (report by Frank Henigman).
```

Back to the thread:

- The [Initialization](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html#h3-Initialization) section of `curs_terminfo(3x)` describes `setupterm`, noting
- in the normal case, where [`use_env`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-use_env) has not been called, `setupterm` allows the `LINES` and `COLUMNS` variables to override the terminal database values.
- The [`use_env`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-use_env) manual page reiterates that, as well as commenting that the values might be obtained from the operating system.
- Again, the changelog mentions that `tput` does this (gets the values from the operating system), e.g., this from [2007](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20070716):

  ```
  + restore a call to obtain screen-size in _nc_setupterm(), which
    is used in tput and other non-screen applications via setupterm()
    (Debian #433357, reported by Florent Bayle, Christian Ohm,
    cf: 20070310).
  ```

In summary, the existing documentation provides answers to almost all questions about the behavior of ncurses, but you have to do some reading.